xml manifest property errors
so i have a video player app i was struggling with a few things so i got someone to help me.
when i got the code back he had used github to sync different versions of the builds. now if i look at the code he sent the xml file has stupid amounts of errors. but if viewed from within his git repository it looks fine no errors everything is recognised.
im a begginner so any help is appreicated.
code screenshot
ive managed to die the issue down to the version of the sdk and gradle. latest sdk with version 17 of the gradle throws an error for unsupported version 7.4.2

Hi and welcome, please add code examples to your question so that we can understand what your problem is. External links should only help to learn more, not contain information needed to answer the question.
